# Issue when trying to generate large dataset

Tags: c, gcc

I want to create large dataset of 60M elements each of dim = 256 (later will be written to a file). I wrote the following to do so:

```
#define N 60000000L
#define DIM 256

int main(){
    int i,j;
    double tmp, *data;
    data = calloc(N*DIM, sizeof(double));
    tmp = 1.0 / RAND_MAX;
    for (i = 0; i < N*DIM; i++) data[i] = (double) rand() * tmp - 0.5;
    // TODO: Save data buffer in file
    free(data);
}
```

But I get this error:

```
main.c:111:19: warning: comparison of constant 7695802368 with expression of type 'int' is always
      true [-Wtautological-constant-out-of-range-compare]
    for (i = 0; i < N*DIM; i++) data[i] = (double) rand() * tmp - 0.5;
                ~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

Can someone hint me please why this issue exists and how to get rid of it? Thank you

Comment: You're allocating 120GB. Your `int` probably tops out at 2G. Might need `long` or even `long long`.

Comment: Use the correct type to index arrays and check the result of `calloc`!

Answer (score 2):

The `int` type on your machine cannot hold a large enough number to ever be >= 7695802368. This means your `int` type is 32 bits. You'll need to use a 64 bit number, `long long int` or probably more appropriately, `unsigned long long int`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `size_t` math with memory allocations and indexing.

It is the Goldilocks type for indexing/sizing, neither too narrow, nor too wide.  Keep in mind that it is some *unsigned* type.

```
//#define N 60000000L
#define N ((size_t) 60000000u)
#define DIM 256

int main(){
    size_t i;// use the best type for indexing
    double tmp, *data;
    size_t n = N*DIM;
    data = calloc(n, sizeof *data);  // de-ref the pointer, 
    if (data) { // check allocation
      tmp = 1.0 / RAND_MAX;
      for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        data[i] = (double) rand() * tmp - 0.5;
```

Answer (score 1):

The warning explains it for you: you're testing a signed integer (that probably maxes out at 2,147,483,647, and is clearly less than the value you're testing against, considering your compiler warning) to see if its value is less than a value that's over 7 billion: it will always be true. Did you maybe mean to do `i < N`?